# How can I place text on top of flexible images?

Tags: html, css

friends!
I`m trying to make a grid of flexible images that come in a row. I dont even need additional div properties for that, works fine as is

```
<div class="container_imggrid"> <img> </div>
```

Css

```
.container_imggrid img {
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 25%;
    height: auto;
}
```

But now i need to add text above my picture, Div with text should be flexible as well.
U can see what i mean at this page http://www.reebok.com/us. That big image with "start designing" sign is flexible until some point, as well as text above it.
I need similar Header properties for my grid elements, but cant position my text block properly.

Can you please help me? Maybe i need absolutely another grid basis for such features?

My interactive fiddle is here: https://jsfiddle.net/CapablancaYEAH/yr809ty8/

P.S. To make things more clear, let me re-phrase.
I need a flexible grid. 
Each separate block of grid is **Square** DIV with image inside and centered header on top of image.
Image should be resized and fit accordingly to div`s width/height (browser window size change).
Header should remain centered with div after any browser window resize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all, I was able to figure out a solution. It uses a trick with

```
 font-size: 0;
```

see https://jsfiddle.net/CapablancaYEAH/68aqv37b/

Answer (score 1):

Just set `position:relative` to parent div and `position:absolute with top and left 50%` for h2 tag.

```css
.container_banner{position:relative;}
.container_banner img{width:100%;height:auto;}
.container_banner h2{position: absolute;  
   right: 0;
   width: 50%;
   left: 0;
   margin: 0 auto;
   text-align: center;
   top: 44%;}
.container_imggrid{width:25%;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="container_banner">
         <h2>Swimming</h2>
            <img src="https://i.yapx.ru/JEvD.jpg" width="1000" height="300">
        </div>
     <div class="container_imggrid container_banner">
            <h2>Swimming</h2>
            <img src="https://i.yapx.ru/JEvC.jpg" width="500" height="500" alt="Подводное плавание">
    </div>
 </div>
```

Make sure your parent div width is same as your `<img>` tag with. It should be same otherwise you need to set your image in background inside the parent div.

Hope this will helpful for you.

Thanks.

Comment: well
i updated fiddle according to ur recomendations
https://jsfiddle.net/CapablancaYEAH/6myb0wed/
As u can see, Header is not being properly positioned when i change window size.

About your second method. Can i make flexible divs grid, so that background image fits div size? I will have square images, so i need divs to maintain proportions 1x1 with resize. Think it will be really easy. Maybe u have an example of such flexible div ?

Comment: After all, I made a solution, if u are interested https://jsfiddle.net/CapablancaYEAH/68aqv37b/

Answer (score 0):

Using `position: relative` (for parent) and `position: absolute` (for child)

https://jsfiddle.net/kaskull/yr809ty8/4/

Comment: Thank you...but what about Header to be centered with image horizontally and vertically? And follow it`s size change accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

You can use media queries at each stage to manipulate the text size at different screen sizes like:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 360px){
    .flx-text{
        font-size:1em;
    }
}
```

Example Fiddle (try resizing for effect):

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/oog99y8d/)

Snippet [Go full screen and resize for effect]:

```css
.container_banner {
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.container_banner img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.container_imggrid img {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 25%;
  height: auto;
}

.container_imggrid h2 {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  max-width: 50%;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 360px) {
  .flx-text {
    font-size: 0.9rem
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 390px) {
  .flx-text {
    font-size: 1.0rem
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 420px) {
  .flx-text {
    font-size: 1.1rem
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 450px) {
  .flx-text {
    font-size: 1.2rem
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) {
  .flx-text {
    font-size: 1.3rem
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 510px) {
  .flx-text {
    font-size: 1.4rem
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 540px) {
  .flx-text {
    font-size: 1.5rem
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 570px) {
  .flx-text {
    font-size: 1.6rem
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .flx-text {
    font-size: 1.7rem
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 630px) {
  .flx-text {
    font-size: 1.8rem
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 660px) {
  .flx-text {
    font-size: 1.9rem
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 690px) {
  .flx-text {
    font-size: 2.0rem
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 720px) {
  .flx-text {
    font-size: 2.1rem
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 750px) {
  .flx-text {
    font-size: 2.2rem
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 780px) {
  .flx-text {
    font-size: 2.3rem
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 810px) {
  .flx-text {
    font-size: 2.4rem
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 840px) {
  .flx-text {
    font-size: 2.5rem
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 870px) {
  .flx-text {
    font-size: 2.6rem
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 900px) {
  .flx-text {
    font-size: 2.7rem
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 930px) {
  .flx-text {
    font-size: 2.8rem
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 960px) {
  .flx-text {
    font-size: 2.9rem
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 360px) {
  .flx-text {
    font-size: 0.8rem
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="container_banner">
    <img src="https://i.yapx.ru/JEvD.jpg" width="1000" height="300">
  </div>

  <div class="container_imggrid">
    <h2 class="flx-text">Swimming</h2>
    <img src="https://i.yapx.ru/JEvC.jpg" width="500" height="500" alt="Подводное плавание">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Excuse me very much, you`ve put so much time into this answer, thank you! But maybe i wasnt very clear ablout what i need?

I need a flexible grid. 
Each separate block of grid is square DIV with image inside and centered header above image.
Image should be resized and fit accordingly to div`s width (browser window size change).
Header should remain centered with div after any browser windiw resize...

Comment: After all, I made a solution, if u are interested https://jsfiddle.net/CapablancaYEAH/68aqv37b/